# Determining raster points inside polygon

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, zonal-statistics, arcgis-10.6

I am trying to perform zonal statistics on a input DEM and a polygon shapefile using ArcPy in Python 2.7. I have done this in Python 3, but want to be able to do it using ArcPy tools in Python 2.7. So far, I successfully got a zonal statistics table, but would like to add another feature.

[image]

I would like to create a list of all the raster points that are inside each of the polygons. So for example, one of the polygons has 1631 raster points inside its bounds. I would like to append a column on the table (or some other place, doesn't have to be in the zonal statistics table) that is a list of all these points with the value being the elevation from the DEM.

Figure shows what I would like to get, the list of elevation values for all the raster points in each polygon.

Has anyone done this before or know of a way to do it using zonal statistics in ArcPy for Python 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.6.1?

Comment: While I have not tried it it looks like you can do this with numpy  library which come installed with 10.6. 
See this link 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html